# Bucket Multiple Columns in Pandas Based on Top N Values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to iterate through multiple dataframe columns looking for the top n values in each column. If the value in the column is in the top n values then keep that value, otherwise bucket in "other". Also, I would like to create new columns from this.

However, I'm not sure how to use `.apply` in this case as it seems like I need to reference both columns and rows.

```
np.random.seed(0)
example_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(15, 5)),columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
cols_to_group = ['a','b','c']
top = 2
```

So for the example below, here's my pseudo code that I'm not sure how to execute:

Pseudo Code:

```
#loop through each column
for column in example_df[cols_to_group]:
    #loop through each value in column and check if it's in top values for the column. 
    for single_value in column:
        if single_value.isin(column.value_counts()[:top].values):
            #return value if it is in top values
            return single_value
        else:
            return "other"
    #create new column in your df that has bucketed values
    example_df[column.name + str("bucketed")+ str(top)]=column
```

Expected output:

Crude example where top = 2.

```
    a   b   c   d   e   a_bucketed b_bucketed
0   4   6   4   3   1     4          6
1   8   8   1   5   7     8          8 
2   8   6   0   0   2     8          6
3   4   1   0   7   4     4          Other
4   7   8   7   7   7     Other      8
```

Comment: For example_df, what is your expected output?

Comment: Input + expected output to be edited into your question please. As you can see, I can't understand anything in the comments.

Comment: a_bucketed should include last row right, and not 4?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. But no treatment for ties has been prescribed.

```
df['a_bucketed'] = np.where(df['a'].isin(df['a'].value_counts().index[:2]), df['a'], 'Other')
df['b_bucketed'] = np.where(df['b'].isin(df['b'].value_counts().index[:2]), df['b'], 'Other')

#     a  b  c  d  e a_bucketed b_bucketed
# 0   5  0  3  3  7      Other      Other
# 1   9  3  5  2  4          9          3
# 2   7  6  8  8  1      Other      Other
# 3   6  7  7  8  1      Other      Other
# 4   5  9  8  9  4      Other          9
# 5   3  0  3  5  0          3      Other
# 6   2  3  8  1  3      Other          3
# 7   3  3  7  0  1          3          3
# 8   9  9  0  4  7          9          9
# 9   3  2  7  2  0          3      Other
# 10  0  4  5  5  6      Other      Other
# 11  8  4  1  4  9      Other      Other
# 12  8  1  1  7  9      Other      Other
# 13  9  3  6  7  2          9          3
# 14  0  3  5  9  4      Other          3
```